# Why does cv2.bilateralFilter behave so differently for different data types?

Tags: python, image, opencv, scikit-image

As the title states, how come `cv2.bilateralFilter` behaves so differently for different dtypes?
`cv2.bilateralFilter` only works for `np.float32` or `np.uint8` dtypes, the documentation says. But when I apply it on my image, the output looks vastly different for the two dtypes.

I am using the skimage functions `img_as_x` to convert between data types, as I have heard that one must **never** use `.astype(x)` when working with images. So my code looks like this:

```
Radargram = img_as_float32(cv2.imread(image)[:,:,::-1])
CropRadGram = (Radargram[700:2450,:,:])[:,:,0]
SigmaAll = 10
RadGramFilter = cv2.bilateralFilter(img_as_ubyte(CropRadGram), -1, SigmaAll, SigmaAll) #As uint8
RadGramFilter2 = cv2.bilateralFilter(CropRadGram, -1, SigmaAll, SigmaAll) #as float32
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20)); plt.imshow(RadGramFilter,cmap='gray')
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20)); plt.imshow(RadGramFilter2,cmap='gray')
RadGramFilterImg = Image.fromarray(img_as_ubyte(RadGramFilter)) #Transform to uint8 and construct image
RadGramFilterImg.save(f'Prepared_CropGrams/{IMG_nr}_RAD_prepared.png') #Save the image
```

And the output of `RadGramFilter` and `RadGramFilter2` can be seen here:

[image: RadGramFilter]

[image: RadGramFilter2]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] as I have heard that one must **never** use `.astype(x)` when working with images.

That highly depends on the used library, and use case! In this very specific example, using `img_as_float32` instead of `.astype(np.float32)` leads to the observed behaviour in the first place!

Having a look at the documentation on [`cv2.bilateralFilter`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga9d7064d478c95d60003cf839430737ed), we see that there's a parameter `sigmaColor`, which you set to `20`, for using both with the `np.uint8` and `np.float32` image. But, `sigmaColor = 20` only properly works for the `np.uint8` case here, since its values are in the range of `[0 ... 255]`. Your `np.float32` image on the other hand has values in the range of `[0.0 ... 1.0]`, which explains the heavy blurring.

So, there are two options to overcome that issue, both involve manually scaling:

1. Use `.astype(np.float32)` in the beginning. Then, you can use `sigmaColor = 20`, but your resulting image will have values in the range `0.0 ... 255.0`, such that you'd need to divide by `255`, e.g. before plotting using `matplotlib`.

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from skimage import img_as_float32, img_as_ubyte

# Use .astype(x) instead of img_as_x
img = cv2.imread('path/to/your/image.jpg')[..., ::-1]
filter_uint8 = cv2.bilateralFilter(img, 200, 200, 200)
filter_float32 = cv2.bilateralFilter(img.astype(np.float32), 200, 200, 200)

plt.figure(1, figsize=(14, 8))
plt.subplot(2, 2, 1), plt.imshow(img), plt.title('Original image')
plt.subplot(2, 2, 2), plt.imshow(filter_uint8), plt.title('uint8 filtered')
plt.subplot(2, 2, 3), plt.imshow(filter_float32), plt.title('float32 filtered')
plt.subplot(2, 2, 4), plt.imshow(filter_float32 / 255), plt.title('float32 filtered, corrected')
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: Option 1]

2. Divide `sigmaColor` by `255` in the `cv2.bilateralFilter` call. So, your result will straightforwardly have values in the range of `0.0 ... 1.0`:

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import img_as_float32, img_as_ubyte

# Scale sigmaColor w.r.t. to float value range of [0.0 ... 1.0]
img = img_as_float32(cv2.imread('path/to/your/image.jpg')[..., ::-1])
filter_uint8 = cv2.bilateralFilter(img_as_ubyte(img), 200, 200, 200)
filter_float32 = cv2.bilateralFilter(img, 200, 200, 200)
filter_float32_corr = cv2.bilateralFilter(img, 200, 200/255, 200)

plt.figure(0, figsize=(14, 8))
plt.subplot(2, 2, 1), plt.imshow(img), plt.title('Original image')
plt.subplot(2, 2, 2), plt.imshow(filter_uint8), plt.title('uint8 filtered')
plt.subplot(2, 2, 3), plt.imshow(filter_float32), plt.title('float32 filtered')
plt.subplot(2, 2, 4), plt.imshow(filter_float32_corr), plt.title('float32 filtered, corrected')
plt.tight_layout(), plt.show()
```

[image: Option 2]

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
Matplotlib:    3.4.0
NumPy:         1.20.2
OpenCV:        4.5.1
scikit-image:  0.18.1
----------------------------------------
```